# How to configure Primefaces Mobile render Kit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I'm trying to set up an dynamic web project with Primefaces Mobile. 
Therefore I'm using tomee as application server. I've also added primfaces-4.0.jar and primefaces-mobile-0.9.4.jar to my `WEB-INF/lib` folder. But I can not render any Primefaces Mobile components. When I try to set up the PrimefacesMobile render kit via

```
<application>
    <default-render-kit-id>PRIMEFACES_MOBILE</default-render-kit-id> 
</application>
```

in my faces-config.xml, I get a NullPointerException.

How do I correctly set up PrimeFaces Mobile for my JSF Application?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify renderkit with GET parameter.

```
http://www.yourapp.com?javax.faces.RenderKitId=PRIMEFACES_MOBILE
```

define in faces-config.xml

```
 <application>
   <default-render-kit-id>PRIMEFACES_MOBILE</default-render-kit-id>
 </application>
```

or specify in view component

```
<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE">
```

**Reference**

[PrimeFaces Community Forum • View topic - set javax.faces.RenderKitId = PRIMEFACES_MOBILE](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16328)